# Bash script which creates new file when output file exceeds certain no. of lines

Tags: bash

I have made a bash script which will append some data into a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOME_DISK=$(df --output=avail /home | awk 'FNR == 2 {print}')
VAR_DISK=$(df --output=avail /var | awk 'FNR == 2 {print}')
TOTAL_MEM=$(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}')
DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:")
CPU_USAGE="$DATE CPU: $CPU_USAGE"
echo $HOME_DISK, $VAR_DISK, $TOTAL_MEM >> /home/neerajR/trail.out
```

In this script, I want to add a functionality to create new files with name trail1.out, trail2.out, when the previous file exceeds 100 lines.

Comment: How are you planning to keep track of how many lines you have appended?  Is there somewhere you can store this data, or are you going to have to read the file each time to count the lines (which could be inefficient?)

Comment: I'll have to read the file each time to count the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a combination of following bash commands and operators:

```
wc -l <file>                   : count the amount of lines 
                                 in a file.
if [$nbr -ge 100]; then ... fi : if-clause.
head -n 100 <file>             : get the first 100 lines 
                                 of a file.
xxx = $((total - 100))         : perform a calculation.
tail -n $xxx <file>            : get the rest of the file.
```